# I want to exclude the component of app.component.html when i am routing to logincomponent

Tags: html, angular2-routing

I am new to Angular2 .I know it is a single page application where we inject different parts over a single page. But just want to know the solution of this thing.My entire layout of HTML is in app.component.html page  .I have given a login button over that page  which redirects me to login component but when i am trying to click the login button whole HTML page is still there and upside or downside html of login page (login works !!) is there depending upon the router-outlet .Want to exclude HTML of app.component over login page

Here is my app.component.html page code :

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="code1">
        <h1>Every Problem has a Solution</h1>

        <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Code Now</a>
          <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
          </div>
</header>

<section class="section-features">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Love Web Designing &mdash; Hotcake Technologies in Market </h2>
        <p class="long-copy">
            Web design encompasses many different skills and disciplines in the production and maintenance of websites. 
            The different areas of web design include web graphic design; interface design; authoring, including
             standardised code and proprietary software; user experience design; and search engine optimization
            </p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span_1_of_4 box">
            <i class="ion-social-html5 icon-big"></i>
            <h3>HTML5</h3>
            <p>HTML5 is the latest evolution of the standard that defines HTML. 
                The term represents two different concepts. It is a new version of the 
                language HTML, with new elements, attributes, and behaviors, and a
                 larger set of technologies that allows the building of more diverse and
                  powerful Web sites and applications</p>
        </div>
         <div class="col span_1_of_4 box">
             <i class="ion-social-css3 icon-big"></i>
            <h3>CSS3</h3>
            <p>CSS3 has been split into "modules". It contains the "old CSS specification" (which has been split into smaller pieces). In addition, new modules are added.

Some of the most important CSS3 modules are:

Selectors
Box Model
Backgrounds and Borders
Image Values and Replaced Content
Text Effects
2D/3D Transformations
Animations
Multiple Column Layout
User Interface</p>
        </div>
         <div class="col span_1_of_4 box">
             <i class="ion-social-angular icon-big"></i>
            <h3>Angular</h3>
            <p>AngularJS (commonly referred to as "Angular.js" or "AngularJS 1.X") is a 
                JavaScript-based open-source front-end web application framework mainly
                 maintained by Google and by a community of individuals and corporations to
                  address many of the challenges encountered in developing single-page applications. 
                  </p>
        </div>
         <div class="col span_1_of_4 box">
             <i class="ion-social-javascript icon-big"></i>
            <h3>Javascript</h3>
            <p>JavaScript ("JS" for short) is a full-fledged dynamic
                 programming language that, when applied to an HTML document, can provide dynamic interactivity on websites.
                  It was invented by Brendan 
                Eich, co-founder of the Mozilla project, the Mozilla Foundation, and the Mozilla Corporation.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="projects">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Want to see Projects &mdash; Simple as 1,2,3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col span_1_of_2 steps_box">
     <img src="../assets/image/projectimage.png" class="mobile_screen">
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_2 steps_box">
    <div class="work_step">
        <div>1</div>
        <p>We have quite a good list of projects in jquery and JavaScript,want to see the projects-keep reading</p>
    </div>
     <div class="work_step">
        <div>2</div>
        <p> It's free -yes you heard correct, Just Sign In with your Gmail Account </p>
    </div>
     <div class="work_step">
        <div>3</div>
        <p>Access the pandora of projects .It will surely help you in learning JavaScript and jquery</p>
    </div>

    ***<a [routerLink]="['/login']" class="btn-app"><img src="../assets/image/login.jpg"></a>***

 </div>

    </div>


</section>

<section class="section-login">

</section>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is my app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './Login/login/login.component';

const approutes:Routes=[
{path: 'login',component:LoginComponent},
{path:'',component:AppComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(
      approutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEnDK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Put the HTML that you do not need on every page into a "home" component or whatever you want to call it.

Your routes then look like this:

```
const approutes:Routes=[
{path: 'login',component:LoginComponent},
{path:'',component:HomeComponent}
];
```

And your AppComponent only has HTML code which is shared by the LoginComponent and HomeComponent and of course the router-outlet.

It could look like this if you want the header to appear in Login and Home:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="code1">
        <h1>Every Problem has a Solution</h1>

        <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Code Now</a>
          <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
          </div>
</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The router-outlet will then be replaced by either the HTML of the HomeComponent or the LoginComponent depending on which route you're currently at.